# show extra fields on different radio button values

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I have three radio buttons, when a visitor clicks the first radio, nothing will happen, when they click the second OR the third some extra fields should show up.

I have following html:

```
<p class="input-group input-radio input-field-workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur"
  <label for="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
    Wenst u een factuur?
    <span class="em-form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <span class="input-group">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" val="Ik heb geen factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" val="Ik heb wel een factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" val="Mijn werkgever zal betalen." type="radio">
  </span>
</p>
```

CSS for the extra fields:

```
.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .input-field-factuur_bedrijf, 
.input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon,
.input-field-factuur_straat, .input-field-factuur_nummer, 
.input-field-factuur_bus, .input-field-factuur_postcode,
.input-field-factuur_gemeente, .input-field-factuur_land,
.input-field-factuur_btw-nummer, .input-field-factuur_opmerkingen {
  display: none;
}
```

I want when radio button 2 or 3 is selected show extra fields. I have following script:

```
$("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {
  $('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_bedrijf').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_straat').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_bus').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_postcode').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_gemeente').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_land').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_btw-nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
  $('.input-field-factuur_opmerkingen').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none');
})
```

This does the job when I select the second radio button, how can I make it visible when the third radio button is selected and then disappear again when the first is selected again?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change to your existing code would be to test whether the clicked item's value is equal to the first radio button's and if so hide the fields, otherwise show them.

That is, change this:

```
$('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres').css('display',
           ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
// and the others
```

...to this:

```
$('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres').css('display',
           ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
// and the others
```

But it would a lot simpler if you did it all in one line by selecting all of the related fields in one go, noting that it is valid for a jQuery selector (like a CSS selector) to list multiple classes:

```js
$("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {

  $('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .input-field-factuur_bedrijf, .input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_straat, .input-field-factuur_nummer, .input-field-factuur_bus, .input-field-factuur_postcode, .input-field-factuur_gemeente, .input-field-factuur_land, .input-field-factuur_btw-nummer, .input-field-factuur_opmerkingen')
    .css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block');

});
```

```css
.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .other-classes-here { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="input-group input-radio input-field-workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur"
  <label for="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
    Wenst u een factuur?
    <span class="em-form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <span class="input-group">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb wel een factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Mijn werkgever zal betalen." type="radio">
  </span>
</p>
<div class="input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres">Sample "field"</div>
```

Having said that, it would be a lot easier to maintain if you gave all of those related fields a common class and then just referenced that class in your JS:

```
$('.common-class-name-here')
    .css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block');
```

If you want to make the hiding and showing a bit fancier you could use the `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()` methods instead of manually setting the `display` property with `.css()`:

```
$('.input-field-whatever...')
    [this.value === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.' ? 'slideUp':'slideDown']();
```

Expand and run the following to see that in context:

```js
$("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {

  $('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .input-field-factuur_bedrijf, .input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_straat, .input-field-factuur_nummer, .input-field-factuur_bus, .input-field-factuur_postcode, .input-field-factuur_gemeente, .input-field-factuur_land, .input-field-factuur_btw-nummer, .input-field-factuur_opmerkingen')
    [this.value === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.' ? 'slideUp':'slideDown']();

});
```

```css
.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .other-classes-here { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="input-group input-radio input-field-workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur"
  <label for="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur">
    Wenst u een factuur?
    <span class="em-form-required">*</span>
  </label>
  <span class="input-group">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Ik heb wel een factuur nodig." type="radio">
    <input class="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" name="workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur" value="Mijn werkgever zal betalen." type="radio">
  </span>
</p>
<div class="input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres">Sample "field"</div>
```

(Note: in your HTML where you have `val="..."` it should be `value="..."`.)